Laravel mailable prettier formatting
I recently installed prettier in my laravel project and everytime I run the fix npm run lint:fix which is prettier --write ./resources/views it reformats the mail in a way that I am it breaks the email formatting in mail.
Here is the mail before and after formating


@component("mail::message")
    You have been invited to join the {{ $invitation->project->name }} team! If you do not have an account, you may
    create one by clicking the button below. After creating an account, you may click the invitation acceptance button
    in this email to accept the team invitation:
    @component("mail::button", ["url" => route("register")])
        {{ __("Create Account") }}
    @endcomponent
    If you already have an account, you may accept this invitation by clicking the button below:
    @component("mail::button", ["url" => $acceptUrl])
        {{ __("Accept Invitation") }}
    @endcomponent
    If you did not expect to receive an invitation to this team, you may discard this email.
@endcomponent





@component("mail::message")
    You have been invited to join the {{ $invitation->project->name }} team! If you do not have an account, you may
    create one by clicking the button below. After creating an account, you may click the invitation acceptance button
    in this email to accept the team invitation:
    @component("mail::button", ["url" => route("register")])
        {{ __("Create Account") }}
    @endcomponent

    If you already have an account, you may accept this invitation by clicking the button below:
    @component("mail::button", ["url" => $acceptUrl])
        {{ __("Accept Invitation") }}
    @endcomponent
    If you did not expect to receive an invitation to this team, you may discard this email.
@endcomponent



This extra space is making the mail to look like this


have you tried wrapping them in divs and spans?

Make prettier ignore the mailable views directory

@IGP I know but thats not the solution.

@Mr.Kenneth yes it does not work

But it is. Mailable views should not be formatted by a tool like prettier or pint due to spaces (indentation) breaking things more often than not.
